# Can not open Form1.cs[Design]

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and inside of the form some UserControls. When I run the program, it works well. But when I want to edit something from the form, it does not load it's contents, it gives some error.
Below are errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @JohnG, No, the designer view is not showing, the code view is open

Comment: I don't think this is the problem of 'SQLite.Interop.dll' because I put the file

Comment: Try to add the following:                                                                         
    <PropertyGroup> 
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
 </PropertyGroup>

Comment: Having something SQL-Related in the Form_Load eventhandler, or  any of the usercontrols in ctor/loaded? Design time ui elements are compiled into some cryptic local cache and if there the dll is missing, it can't compile the control

Comment: @ScareCrow, added them but didn't work

Comment: Have you installed the package for SQLite? @GamerInTheGame

Comment: @ScareCrow, yes I did

Comment: The problem is probably due to you having a Database call in your onLoad Event chain somewhere. Perform your DB Call after checking if(!DesignMode) doDBCall;

Comment: @Democrats, thanks. It solved the problem